# How to filter both the keys and values of a dict in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to achieve a customized dict that return the items according to an attribute `mode` as follows:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyDict, self).__init__()
        self.mode = True

mydict = MyDict()
# fill data {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, ..., 9:9}
for i in range(10):
    mydict[i] = i
```

`mydict.mode` acts as a filter. For example, when `mydict.mode` is `True`, `mydict` works like it only has the first half items, and when `mydict.mode` is `False`, it only contains the remaining data.

```
mydict.mode=True
print(mydict)         # {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4}
print(mydict.keys())  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

mydict.mode=False
print(mydict)         # {5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 8:8, 9:9}
print(mydict.keys())  # [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The above code is only a simple example, the support for more complex filters is also expected.

At first, I want to filter items within the functions of dict. The problem is that the class dict in python is implemented by C language rather than python, I don't know which and where is the most original iter function. So I have to rewrite all functions for my customized dict, like `keys()`, `items()`, `values()`, `__contains__`, `__getitem__` ...

Is there any better idea to achieve my customized dict?

Comment: There is nothing in your code to show how *mode* is used

Comment: So suppose the dictionary has 10 key-value pairs in total, you'd want it to return the first 5 for `mode == True` and the last 5 for `mode == False`.

Comment: If you don't know which methods you need to implement, you should write some client-centric code against: `class MyDict:`, ie just temporarily don't inherit from `dict`. Then the errors will be about the missing methods you need to implement.

Comment: @LancelotduLac sry, I have updated the question

Comment: @IshanShishodiya Yes, I take it as a simple example. Of course I hope the solution can also support a more complex filter, for example, filter by odd or even number.

Comment: You can implement a MutableMapping instead of dict

Comment: It might be easier if you don't sub-class *dict*. Just have a *dict* object within your class and then implement the functions you need to access it. Then you don't have to worry about how *dict* implements anything

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a lot that you need to implement - just 3 higher level function (keys, values, items) and 3 dunder functions (setitem, getitem, contains). Add a few helper functions to keep the code concise then you end up with:

```
class MyDict:
    def __init__(self, mode=True):
        self._dict = dict()
        self._mode = mode
    @property
    def mode(self):
        return self._mode
    @mode.setter
    def mode(self, mode):
        self._mode = mode
    def __split(self, list_):
        mid = len(self._dict) // 2
        return list_[:mid] if self._mode else list_[mid:]
    def __sublistK(self):
        return self.__split(list(self._dict.keys()))
    def __sublistV(self):
        return self.__split(list(self._dict.values()))
    def __sublistI(self):
        return self.__split(list(self._dict.items()))
    def keys(self):
        for k in self.__sublistK():
            yield k
    def values(self):
        for v in self.__sublistV():
            yield v
    def items(self):
        for k, v in self.__sublistI():
            yield k, v
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self._dict[k] = v
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if k in self:
            return self._dict[k]
    def __contains__(self, k):
        return k in self.__sublistK()
```

Now you can use this as a regular dictionary except that the output will be influenced by the mode value

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you,

```
mydict = MyDict()

for i in range(11):
  mydict[i] = i

mid_index = int(len(mydict.keys()) / 2)

if mydict.mode == True:
  new_keys = list(mydict.keys())[:mid_index]
  new_values = list(mydict.values())[:mid_index]

  new_dict = dict(zip(new_keys, new_values))

  print(new_dict)

else:
  new_keys = list(mydict.keys())[mid_index:]
  new_values = list(mydict.values())[mid_index:]

  new_dict = dict(zip(new_keys, new_values))

  print(new_dict)
```

This code first identifies the dictionary's middle key's index and then returns the values according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I rewrite all buildin functions of `dict`, including

- `__getitem__`
- `__setattr__`
- `values`
- `items`
- `keys`
- `get`
- `__contains__`.

Taking `keys` as an example:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, filter):
        self.filter = filter

    def keys(self):
        return self.filter(super().keys())
```

where `filter` is a customized filter function.

Also, I notice that `MyDict().get("key", default=None)` doesn't call the function `__getitem__`, and I still need to rewrite it.